# Unable to take multiple String input using scanner in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, string-concatenation

I have been trying to do a program in which i have to concat three strings in java.I am taking input from user using Scanner.It compiles perfect but when i run it,it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at Night.main(Night.java:10)
```

This is my code:

```html
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

class Demo {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  String fn;
  String mn;
  String ln;
  String fmn, lmn;
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  fn = sc.nextLine();
  mn = sc.nextLine();
  ln = sc.nextLine();
  fmn = fn.concat(mn);
  lmn = fmn.concat(ln);
  System.out.println("The Full name of candidate is : " + lmn);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your current code in `Demo` class is working fine. Can you check again?! The exception is from `Night.main(Night.java:10)`. If you still have the same error, can you check if there is any Night class in your working space?!

Hope this help.

Comment: It Worked guys.It was just a silly mistake ,I Saved the program by name "Night.java" though my class name was VecDemo. Thank you All members for your help..Highly appreciated

Comment: Haha. That's fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine. Remove the `[]` near class declaration.

```
class VecDemo
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String fn;
    String mn;
    String ln;
    String fmn,lmn;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    fn=sc.nextLine();
    mn=sc.nextLine();
    ln=sc.nextLine();
    fmn=fn.concat(mn);
    lmn=fmn.concat(ln);
    System.out.println("The Full name of candidate is : " + lmn);
}
}
```

Refer the attachment.

[image: Execution]